# Linux Text editors able to work with very, very long lines & fixed length records

Tags: linux, text-editors

I've got a fairly simple problem here: I have a piece of text which is one giant big line (~150,000 characters). No line breaks, and it's a fixed-length flat file (i.e. it was produced by a `COBOL` program), so introducing line breaks is not only awkward, it's actively unhelpful if I'm trying to make changes to the file.

Most text editors struggle with a single line that big (`less` doesn't like it, `Gedit` doesn't like it, `nano` doesn't like it, I've heard `vim` doesn't like it, etc), though they do work.

Does anyone have any suggestions for an editor that would be better suited to the data I'm working with? It's only a single line, but it still causes more problems than a 1GiB+ text file with normal-length lines would...

Would be even better if it would work with `EBCDIC` and not barf when it encounters null bytes, or mangle them when writing back out (some fields are binary-encoded decimals).

Please note, this isn't about files that are big in terms of raw size - the file contains only a single line - but about the fact that most editors aren't optimized to cope with very long lines.

Comment: @smc see his last paragraph where he says this isn't about big in terms of raw size

Comment: Perhaps you could show a screenshot of how the obvious things to try - vim/gvim or emacs fails (if they do!)?

Comment: @barlop (+1), you are correct, I have removed my comment

Comment: @barlop They don't fail in the sense of not working, they just tend to be really slow. I've also pasted long lines into Eclipse once or twice, and that was a *really* bad idea - completely locked it up, actually had to kill the process.

Comment: @ipsi edit that point into your question, about vim and emacs being very slow for long lines.. if that's what you're saying. Is this a particular issue with just pasting? Or is it after pasting too?

Comment: @ipsi how about a command to copy from clipboard to file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749544/pipe-to-from-clipboard

Comment: Have you just _tried_ vim? You heard it's going to be slow, but why don't you just give it a try? It won't cost you much.

Comment: As others have said, that is *not* a text file. It is a binary file, which just happens to contain mostly text. Better think of it as one. So, find a hex editor which is most helpful with your specific editing needs. One place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors . Many seem to support EBCDIC too.

Comment: OK, thanks for that guys. I will give `vim` a shot, and I will also look into hex editors. I've been using `hexdump` for viewing it, honestly not sure why it never occurred to me to use a hex editor to edit it. (Also, apologies to the site as a whole for asking an off-topic question - I swear I looked up what was appropriate for the site, so yay for reading fail...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a file like the way you are describing is, for practical purposes, acting like a binary file and you should treat it as such.

You could attack it with a hex editor, but that doesn't help you with the EBCIDC part.

If you have to do a lot of editing on this file and are intimately familiar with its fixed-length record format, it may be worth your time to whip up something in Perl or another language (I suggest Perl because it's old and would very likely have modules that convert UTF-8, etc. to EBCIDC), that would work with this file's specific format.

Answer (score 6):

I actually *just tried* vim on a file with a single line of 150000 characters and it ran smooth as silk.

So I guess you should really give it a go, if you didn't just because `you heard vim doesn't like such kind of files`.

Here's how I got my file:

```
seq 150000 | while read num; do echo -n "b" ; done > megaline.txt
```

Comment: I've seen Vim handle large files well and I've seen Vim handle large files poorly. It very much depends on the configuration. (My main configuration handles long lines poorly, but it doesn't come up often so I haven't investigated lately)

Comment: Turn syntax highlighting off if it runs slowly.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the same method as Dakatine with my emacs install and it worked fine. No hangups, nothing. If you're editing plain text (i.e. not doing any of the kind of analysis that a mode for a programming language requires, in `text-mode`), it's going to be really, really hard to lock up emacs. The behavior that you're seeing with Eclipse is probably a reflection of the fact that Eclipse is trying to do some sort of analysis on the text as it renders it -- ditto for Gedit. I also can't reproduce your issue with `less` -- it comes out fine for me.

Comment: Plus you've got things like [CobolMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CobolMode) and [Ebcidic Table](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EbcdicTable) that might help.

Comment: I'm having an issue in emacs at the end of the file when it's trying to match up braces.  (It's a JSON file, but I'm using `text-mode`.)

Answer (score 3):

Give it a try: [JEdit - A programmer editor](http://www.jedit.org/)

It's got some advanced buffering features, and highly optimized I/O, but takes a while to start up (due to JVM).
I've been using it to view & edit over 1GiB files without any trouble - at least on Debian.
I cannot guarantee it will behave as good on windows though... :)

Comment: Although I can't find High DPI support yet, I can attest it works on long lines where gedit crashed.